# Binding doesn't get updated in DefiningGeometry

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have two DPs that I update in a `DefiningGeometry` get:

```
protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
{
    get
    {
        StartSc = sc.Transform(Start);
        EndSc = sc.Transform(End);
        //Start and End are also dependencies properties.    
    ...
    }
}
```

I bind to StartSc and EndSc but the target never gets updated, it always stays the default value of 0. Start and End change, so that is not the issue, I am wondering if assignment in the `DefiningGeometry` get doesn't have an effect on the properties. Does anyone see any obvious mistake?

**Note:** I had the same variables names which were hiding the DPs from a derived class, removing the hiding the above code worked, but the bellow answer works either way.

Comment: The obvious mistake is that you set things in a getter in the first place.

Comment: @H.B. Would that not update the DPs or is it a design mistake?

Comment: You just should in general not set values in a getter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bind to DPs and you are in the control's code you want to use [`SetCurrentValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue.aspx) *(not the CLR-wrappers (`StartSc` & `EndSc`) which use `SetValue`)* because otherwise you overwrite the existing bindings with the concrete value.

Also as i said, avoid doing things in getters, it is really hard to tell when and how often they get called.

Comment: I had the same var names in the derived class which was hiding the DPs, so they were never getting set, once I removed those variables the above code worked. Either way your answer worked. Thank you.